# How continue commands on .bat file if bitsadmin gives error

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I use bitsadmin in cmd to download some files

```
bitsadmin /transfer Download /download /priority FOREGROUND "url" "destination"
```

But when it gives errors the bat file completely stop and don't continue to execute other commands

How it's possible to solve this problem?

Comment: I am skeptical to provide any solution without seeing more of the code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I mean, I'm personally unable to recreate your issue.  When I try to download a file that doesn't exist or from a host that doesn't exist, `bitsadmin` errors but the script continues.  You've got something else going on with your script.

But if you want to insulate your script from `bitsadmin`'s crashy behavior, you could rewrite it as an asynchronous download, then use its `/setnotifycommandline` switch to notify your main script when it's finished.  Here's an example:

```batch
@echo off & setlocal

set "URL=https://URL"
set "SAVETO=%CD%\OUTFILE"

for /f %%I in ('bitsadmin /rawreturn /create %random%') do set "dljob=%%~I"
set "signal=%dljob:~-13,-1%"
for %%I in (waitfor.exe) do set "waitfor=%%~$PATH:I"

>NUL (
    bitsadmin /setnotifycmdline %dljob% "%waitfor%" "%waitfor% /s %computername% /si %signal%"
    bitsadmin /addfile %dljob% "%URL%" "%SAVETO%"
    bitsadmin /setpriority %dljob% FOREGROUND
    start /b "" bitsadmin /resume %dljob%
    waitfor /t 5 %signal%
)
for /f %%I in ('bitsadmin /rawreturn /geterrorcount %dljob%') do cmd /c exit /b %%I && (
    echo Download successful.
) || (
    bitsadmin /geterror %dljob%
)
>NUL bitsadmin /complete %dljob%
```

The `waitfor` command waits for 5 seconds for a "finished" signal.  Increase that value if appropriate.

Anyway, if `bitsadmin` runs asynchronously (as happens when you `start /b`), it can crash all it wants to without affecting your main batch thread.  It should only affect the child thread that `start /b` forked.